# Use binding redirects from custom config file

Tags: c#

I have a .NET service/console application that takes a config file. The default for `MyApp.exe` is `MyApp.exe.config` in the directory of the application, but I want it to be `..\Web.config`.

So I found that I can load that config file like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        if (File.Exists("..\\Web.config"))
        {
            var path = Path.GetFullPath("..\\Web.config");
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APPBASE", "..");
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path);
```

This works well for the settings I want to use, but the service needs some runtime binding redirects, and these are loaded before I switch config files.

Is there a way to tell my application to switch to `..\Web.config` before evaluating `bindingRedirect`?

Comment: why you want to do that? maybe there's other solution to the real problem that you want to solve with this approach?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I want to get rid of half a dozen config file duplicates which have to be kept in sync with each other and the Web.config file.

Comment: If this were possible, it'd be a bug in the framework. Assemblies can be loaded before a single line of your code is ever executed, so the binding redirects *better* be applied before that. If you really want this, make a small loader that starts the real application with your desired configuration path. Of course, that can't work for services because those must remain where they are to communicate with the SCM. You could load your main code in a new AppDomain, if you really wanted to, but due to shared assembly loading there's no guarantee the redirects work properly.

Comment: Another option is to forego binding redirects and add a handler to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`. This requires you to do your own plumbing, though, so there's no guarantee that's easier.